# Ruby avoiding "stack level too deep" with link

Tags: ruby

So I have a "stack level too deep" error, and I'm pretty sure I know what's causing it.  I am working on a tile based game, and I have all the tiles, and for convenience (to save looking it up every time I need to use pathfinding), each tile has a "nearby" array containing the 8 neighbours.

However, when I go to print out some objects for debugging, I am frequently running into the "stack level too deep" error.  I think that it is because each tile has neighbouring tiles in the "nearby" array, which then refer back to the original tile, creating a loop when trying to print all objects.

I can live with this, but it would be much nicer if I could have my cake and eat it too.  I can avoid it by referring to tiles by id or coordinates, instead of direct reference to object.  Disadvantage is this means searching for the object every time.

So, is there a way to maintain my current code but prevent the "nearby" array from being printed in output so that it stops sanely?

Hope that's clear!  Current code:

```
class Tile
    attr_accessor :type, :x, :y, :z, :nearby, :t_id

    @type = 0

    @@count = 0

    def initialize(x, y, z, type)
        @x = x
        @y = y
        @z = z
        @t_id = @@count
        @@count += 1

        @nearby = [] 

        @type = type
    end
end
```

Comment: you should build a tree and prevent leafs from referencing their roots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby prints the return of the [inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method of an object when you pass it to [p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p). You can override inspect on your class to make it return a string with only the information that would be useful for you.

For instance:

```
class A
  def inspect
    "printing an instance of A"
  end
end
```

When you print it:

```
irb> a = A.new    
irb> p a    
printing an instance of A
```